# Tcpclient binaryreader not receiving a specific packet C#

Tags: c#, tcpclient, packets, binaryreader, binarywriter

So let me make this clear, I'm quite new to packets and networking.

So I'm working on a project where there'll be 1 server and 4 clients all connected to the server.
I've gotten most of my packets working, both sides but I've gotten problems with this one.
Here's the layout:

```
bw.Write(WGG_SendKaart);
bw.Write(index); //Int32
bw.Write(k.Nummer); //Int32
bw.Write(k.Soort.soort); //String
bw.Flush();
```

And the receiving part:

```
byte type = br.ReadByte();
int index = br.ReadInt32();
int nr = br.ReadInt32();
string soort = br.ReadString();
```

Okay so here comes the weird part. When the packet has a 1 or a 2 in the index variable it successfully sends and receives, however if it has another number (in this case 0-3) it would not receive. Not even the packet type byte would be received by the client.

For some context:
I'm sending this packet 4 times to 4 clients. Let's say the first time Client1 gets 0 as index, client2 gets 1 as index, client3 gets 2 as index and client4 gets 3 as index. Only Client2 & Client3 would receive their packet.
Then the second time The indexes get +1 and 3 becomes 0. So this time you'd think Client1 would receive the packet because he's got 1 as index right? Nope. He doesn't get anything.

Could really use some help here. If you need any more code let me know.

Comment: Hi...welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Networking-related questions in particular can be challenging to form a minimal, complete code example, but it is especially important in that case to do so. NOTE: the first and most important thing you need to know about TCP is that the concept of "packet", "message", etc. is foreign to the TCP protocol itself. Your (apparent?) use of `BinaryReader` should insulate you from that here, but it's still an important point to understand.

Comment: I'm confused. You're talking about sending packets over a network, but you're (apparently) using `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`, which are used for binary *file* access. What exactly are you trying to do?